# Why does the google appengine api datastore Entity not have an empty constructor?

Tags: google-app-engine, constructor, entity, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

When I pass an entity from ios to a backendAPI method that expects an entity I get the error "... No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity] ..." Why does the google appengine api datastore Entity not have an empty constructor? Also, is there a way for me to provide a suitable constructor other than using objectify? I tried using objectify and was able to get rid of the error but then the values of all my properties were deleted and set to null.

Comment: Can you share your code to better understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming you're using Java language)

There is no empty-constructor because to create an `Entity` you need to specify a `Key` or a `Kind-Id/Name`

Source: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity